# Entity framework asp.net MVC3 .NET 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity

I Have a little snag. With my asp.net mvc3 application.
When I trying to compile my app I obtain this Error

**Error   2   'Blog.Domain.Concrete.EFEntryRepository' does not implement interface member 'Blog.Domain.Abstract.IEntryRepository.SaveEntry(Blog.Domain.Entities.Entry)'  D:\dokumenty\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MVC3\Blog\Blog.Domain\Concrete\EFEntryRepository.cs    10  19  Blog.Domain**

This is my Interface.

```
namespace Blog.Domain.Abstract
{
     public interface IEntryRepository
     {
          IQueryable<Entry> Entries { get; }
          void SaveEntry(Entry entry);
          void DeleteEntry(Entry entry);
     }
}
```

And this is my implementation of it.

```
public class EFEntryRepository : IEntryRepository
     {
          private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

          public IQueryable<Entry> Entries
          {
               get { return context.Entries; }
          }

          public void SaveEntry(Entry entry)
          {
               if (entry.EntryID == 0)
                    context.Entries.Add(entry);
               context.SaveChanges();
          }
          public void DeleteEntry(Entry entry)
          {
               context.Entries.Remove(entry);
               context.SaveChanges();
          }

     }
```

This is link to my project. http://sigma.ug.edu.pl/~kkubacki/Blog.zip //NEW
Now I is compiling.

What I Do Wrong ?

I have new Information about the bug. Now the solution is compiling but the application crashes with the bug information 
**"{"The type 'Blog.Domain.Concrete.Entry' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject."} "** Visual studio shows bug in the **EFEntryRepository**  class.

I don't know what to do please help.

**OK Problem IS Solved.**

Comment: At first glance it looks like it should compile just fine.  I would incrementally remove code blocks until it works then incrementally restore until it breaks to find culprit.  Would there be another type of Entry in alternate namespace?

Comment: It is not another type of Entry in alternate space.

Comment: I don't believe the issue is in the code block you provided above.  If you remove SaveEntry(...) altogether; does DeleteEntry then produce a similar compile error?

Comment: I removed SaveEntry , and I compile It and I get the same error.

Comment: Exact same error which references "SaveEntry" or something similar?

Comment: So the error is definitely somewhere else.  And you removed "all" SaveEntry such that it could not be found in your entire solution?  That might be a large question but something more is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different `Entry` classes in different namespaces.

- `Blog.Domain.Entities.Entry`
- `Blog.Domain.Concrete.Entry`

The interface is referring to one and the implementation is referring to the other.

Comment: I dont see  Entry class in Blog.Domain.Concrete .

Comment: OK I changed Entry to Blog.Domain.Entities.Entry in NinjectControllerFactory.

Now The solution is compiling but I still have bugs. 
  "The type 'Blog.Domain.Concrete.Entry' was not mapped."

Error is in 12-th Line of Blog.Domain.Concrete.EFEntryRepository.cs

Line 10:      public class EFEntryRepository : IEntryRepository
Line 11:      {
Line 12:           private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
Line 13: 
Line 14:           public IQueryable<Entry> Entries